# How to use <spring:url /> with an <a> tag?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jstl

Can I use `<spring:url value="/something" />` inside of an `<a>` tag?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
 <spring:url value="/something" var="url" htmlEscape="true"/>
 <a href="${url}">...</a>
```

But you an also use c:url

```
 <c:url value="/something" var="url"/>
 <a href="<c:out value='${url}'/>">...</a>
```

The one important difference between `c:url` and `spring:url` is, that `c:url` does not html encode the created url. But for a valid url the `&` between the url parameters must be a `&amp;`. So you need the `c:out` to escape it. -- In `spring:url` you have this functionality already included (if I understand the documentation correct).

Namespaces:

- `xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags"`
- `xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"`

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring.tld.html#spring.tld.url

Comment: You can also use the c:url tag within the href attribute of the anchor tag directly, as in
    <a href="<c:url value='/something' />" >...</a>

Comment: @digitaljoel: This correct -- as long as no escaping is needed -- stacking a-href c:out and c:url would cause strange (IDE/Eclipse) problems because there are only two type of apostrophe (`"` and `'`) -- (be aware of the problem that even if you do not define a parameter, c:out could add a parameter for session handling (if cookies are disabled))

Comment: would I need to use `<c:out` like in the second example? or could I just use `${}` like in the first? I'm either getting links that link to the current page or to something like this: `http://localhost/%3Cspring:url%20value=`

Comment: @213897 when using spring:url with htmlEncoding="true" then ${} is ok, else you need c:out for encoding

Comment: @Ralph correct, I figured that was assumed since you had covered the escaping in your excellent answer.  As for the quoting problem, I've seen it where the same type of quote was used and eclipse didn't complain, but that doesn't mean it's the best way to go.  For simple values though, I think having it in the href attribute directly is ok.

Comment: @213897 - no problem, if it helped you, feel free to accept the answer. (click the checkmark)

Comment: Additionally, `<spring:url />` allows the usage of inner `<spring:param />` elements for setting request parameters.

Comment: What are the namespace URLs for `c:` and `spring:` there?

Comment: @rakslice: see my extended answer

Comment: @marchWest: you are rigth, the correct attribute name is: `htmlEscape` - I have updated the answer - thanks

Comment: Why use  "<a href="<c:out value='${url}'/>">...</a>" when you can use  <a href="${url}">...</a>?

Comment: @borjab: To escape the "&" character (if the url has two or more request parameters)