# how to avoid <spring:url />ing multiple times

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jstl

I'm working with `<spring:url />` because our project is located at `domain/ProjectName/mappings/here`.  I posted about some confusion here: [How to use <spring:url /> with an <a> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007210/how-to-use-springurl-with-an-a-tag) .  Now the issue I'm having is because I'm saving the URLS to a database.  So I get URLs like `domain/ProjectName/ProjectName/mappings/here`.  How can I avoid this?  If spring needs to add `ProjectName`, shouldn't it be able to check for it's existence first?

Comment: I don't quite follow you... maybe provide some example JSP code and explain how that is getting into the database? Have you tried plain links like: <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/mappings/here"/> (if you don't need the host/domain part)

Comment: it's an issue with me sending `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/mappings/here` to the server, then later adding another `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`.  I was just curious if <spring:url /> could parse that out somehow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your last comment, **yes** the `spring:url` tag does have an option to **exclude** the contextPath portion of the URL. Just set the `context` attribute to an empty string:

```
<spring:url var="mappingLink" context="" value="/mappings/here" />
```

I'm not sure this will fix your problem though, as it seems unlikely that the `spring:url` tag is adding the contextPath twice. That seems more likely to be happening somewhere else in your code. Either way this should help you find out.