# Spring MVC mapping - why path is changing?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, path, navigation

I have this piece of code:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="login/authUser", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String authUser(@RequestParam("login") String login,
                        @RequestParam("password") String password, ModelMap model)
(...)
```

Which should catch user's authentication:

```
<div id ="loginBar">
        <form id="loginForm" action="login/authUser" method="post">
            <label>Login:</label>
            <input id="login" type="text" title="podaj login" name="login"/><br><br>
            <label>Hasło:</label>
            <input id ="password" type="password" title="podaj haslo, minimum 8 znaków" name="password"><br>
            <input id ="loginAuthorisationFailed" type="text"/><br>
            <input id="loginButton" type="submit" value="Zaloguj"><br>
        </form>
    </div>
```

And if it's bad, it should return index.jsp and information about bad data

```
(...)
else{
            model.put("info", "Bad data!");
            return "index";
```

Info goes to the h1 HTML tag:

```
 <h1>${info}</h1>
```

And this is path then I see in browser:

```
http://localhost:8084/pracainz/login/authUser
```

But then I try to log again, path in browser is different:

```
http://localhost:8084/pracainz/login/login/authUser
```

and Tomcat shows me error:

```
The requested resource () is not available.
```

It adds extra "/login" and I don't know why. What can I do to stop form behaving in this way, what can I do to force ,,reset" of path every time when I try to send form to Spring?

Unfortunately, this is not working:

```
action="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/login/authUser"
```

I would be very happy if anybody want to help me.

Thank you in advance!

**SOLVED:**
Solution:

I should use:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
(...)

<form:form id="loginForm" action="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/login/authUser" method="post">
 (...)
</form:form>
```

Instead simple  HTML tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Spring tag library and more specifically `spring:url` to create the correct url for action. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007210/how-to-use-springurl-with-an-a-tag) SO question for details

Comment: thanks, I find also different solution; I should use <form:form> Spring tag instead simple HMTL <form>