# Nested Spring EL does not work

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a static global String constant named **var** within a bean id globalConstants. In my jsp, I can grab the content of it by **${globalConstants.var}** . Now my var has a url like below:

```
<a href="<spring:url value="/fan/foo.html"/>">Foo</a>
```

However, the  tag does not get evaluated to the correct url. But instead the whole  tag is there. Is there anyway for my spring tags in the **var** variable get evaluated upon calling it ? Specifically, the given url should be something like this

```
 <a href="/abc/fan/foo.html">Foo</a>
```

Comment: Did you try it without the outer quotes? Or switching one of the quote pairs to single quotes?

Comment: Neither worked. the <spring:url ... /> still there and the link does not work. It links to spring:url stuff on the browser's address bar

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007210/how-to-use-springurl-with-an-a-tag

Comment: no, its not. 2 different issues. Mine is way harder!

Comment: Please clarify what you want. I don't see any EL in the JSP snippet you posted. Post what you actually have and what you want it to do.

Comment: my EL is JSP is ${globalConstants.var} and the string constant var has  <a href="<spring:url value="/fan/foo.html"/>">Foo</a> in it that not getting evaluated. Hence the nested EL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have something like

```
public class Constants {
    private String var = "<a href=\"<spring:url value=\"/fan/foo.html\"/>\">Foo</a>";
    public String getVar() {
        return var;
    }
}
```

and then

```
model.addAttribute("globalConstants", new Constants());
```

and

```
${globalConstants.var}
```

> Is there anyway for my spring tags in the var variable get evaluated upon calling it

No, there is only one component at play here: the Expression Language resolver. It will see `${..}` and perform the appropriate logic to resolve the expression and write the `String` result directly to the `HttpServletResponse` `OutputStream`.

You simply cannot do what you're asking and you shouldn't. Keep your view elements and your Java code separate (unless the Java code is meant to write to the response).

If you need something like a global holder for

```
<a href="<spring:url value="/fan/foo.html"/>">Foo</a>
```

put it in its own JSP and `import` it in each JSP you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have forgot to import taglib like:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
```

then below line should work:

```
 <a href='<spring:url value="/fan/foo.html"/>'>Foo</a>
```

Comment: its not like that. The anchor is part of a string variable. The content of the string variable is like this ${globalConstants.var} . However, the url:spring tag in the variable is not getting evaluated. Hence, I cant have a proper link