# spring:url shows wrong URL

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

i have a problem with spring url tag in my jsp page.
Here is my index.jsp page:

```html
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<spring:url var="registrationUrl" value="/register"/>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Index page</h2>
    <a href="${registrationUrl}">Register</a>
</body>
</html>
```

after clicking on "Register" link my URL format looks like this:
http://localhost:8080/$%7BregistrationUrl%7D

instead of:
http://localhost:8080/register

so the question: what i am missing?

Comment: Are you sure the page is being processed as JSP and not being sent as plain, static HTML? Can you view it in your browser's "view source" and make sure all the scriptlets are gone?

Comment: yea, i viewed in browser the page looks like plain HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I didn't expect but the problem was in my web.xml. It used old xml schema:

```html
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
```

so i replice this to newest schema:

```html
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">
```

Thanks all to try help me.
P.S. Sorry for my bad engilsh.

Answer (score 2):

@Dmitriy Tatarenko's answer works for me too.. one change here is to carefully make the replacement as follows:

From something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Application Name</display-name>
</web-app>
```

to:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">

  <display-name>Application Name</display-name>
</web-app>
```

Note: Do not chop off the <!DOCTYPE...> line as the packaging may not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<spring:url value="/something" var="url" htmlEscape="true"/>
 <a href="${url}">...</a>

 <c:url value="/something" var="url"/>
 <a href="<c:out value='${url}'/>">...</a>
```

The one important difference between c:url and spring:url is, that c:url does not html encode the created url. But for a valid url the & between the url parameters must be a &. So you need the c:out to escape it. -- In spring:url you have this functionality already included (if I understand the documentation correct).

Answer (score 0):

You may try to  add `htmlEscape="true"` to your spring:url tag.
Should be for your particular case :

```
<spring:url var="registrationUrl" value="/register"  htmlEscape="true"/>
```

May be duplicate of another stackoverflow thread. See :
[How to use <spring:url /> with an <a> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007210/how-to-use-springurl-with-an-a-tag)

Sam

Comment: after adding htmlEscape="true" same effect (