# Spring mvc: I cant map form action url to controller action

Tags: spring, forms, spring-mvc, jsp-tags, request-mapping

I apologize in advance if this or a similar question has already been asked, but I could not find a suitable answer.

I have a simple form like this in `EditUser.jsp` (mapped to: `.../admin/users/edit/{userId}`):

```
<form action="/admin/users/edit/addRole/${user.userId}" method="POST">
    <select name="role">
        <c:forEach var="role" items="${roles}">
            <option value="${role}">${role}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" value="AddRole">Add Role</button>
</form>
```

And `@RequestMapping` like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/users/edit/addRole/${userId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addUserRole(
        Model model,
        @RequestParam("role") String role, 
        @PathVariable(value="userId") long userId) 
{
    ...

    return "redirect:/admin/users/edit/${userId}";
}
```

The problem is the result of the request: `HTTP Status 404 - /admin/users/edit/addRole/7`- "The requested resource is not available" (7 is some user id). A cannot map the `POST` request to the controller action. I already tried with `th:action` but it redirects me to the previous page `.../admin/users`.

Any help pointers appreciated .

Comment: `th:action` is a thymeleaf attribute, but you use jsp's, so this will not help

Answer (score 1):

I think you url is wrong. As long as you do not deploy the application in the servlets container root path, it will not work because the url is missing the applications name. So a correct url would be something like:

```
<form action="myAppName/admin/users/edit/addRole/${user.userId}" method="POST">
```

But better would been using `<c:url>` or `<spring:url>`-tag this adds the application name to the url (if the given url starts with an `/`)

```
<form action="<c:url value="/admin/users/edit/addRole/${user.userId}" />" method="POST">
```

for some more information have a look at this two answers:

- [How to use relative paths without including the context root name?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33855917/280244) (the highes ranked answer of BalusC is for an quite old jsp version (<2.0)) so take the answer with the c:url tag
- [How to use  with an  tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5007909/280244)

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. Your suggested resources are very useful but did not help me - the problem still persist.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the error - `$` sign in `@RequestMapping` annotation. A just removе `$` from annotation and from `return "...url"` and that's all.